# Deserializing a list of ints with Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm trying to communicate with a Rest service that returns a simple JSON array of ints, e.g.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I have the following code to make the call via WebClient:

```
    client.get()
        .uri("/achievements")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux<Int>()
        .doOnNext { println(it) }
        .doOnError { it.printStackTrace() }
        .blockLast()
```

However, Spring returns me an empty Flux. If I replace the `bodyToFlux` call with a `bodyToMono<List<Int>>`, then Spring is able to deserialize the response as expected. The drawback being that I have to then manually change it back to a Flux with a redundant `flatMapIterable { it }`

Am I missing something or are `bodyToFlux` and `bodyToMono` only meant to be used with Jackson POJOs?

Comment: which version of Spring Framework are you using? This might be related to this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16166

Comment: Thank you! That issue is exactly what my problem is. I'm currently using 5.0.2 since that's the stable release. I tried with the 5.0.3 snapshot but it looks like the fix hasn't arrived in it yet. If you don't mind adding your comment as an answer, I can mark it and close the question.

Comment: This was fixed back in December - if it still doesn't work for you, then it's a different issue. Could you create an new issue on https://jira.spring.io?

Comment: Digging deeper, I realize how my issue is slightly different. The issue you linked only addresses scalar top-level values. My issue is caused by a scalar array. I'll make a new issue.

Comment: Thanks! If you can, could you publish a minimal sample on github so that we can reproduce and hunt down the bug?

Comment: Created a new ticket and a sample project. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16407

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16407) in Spring's WebClient implementation.